# Turning a string into a variable call

Tags: lua

I want to set a variable from a string. For example, if `string = 'variable'` and later on I wanna set `variable`, the variable inside `string`, to a new value. How would I do that?

I've heard about something like `_G` before a string value in some way, and somehow that should convert that into a variable call. I'm probably saying a nonsense but don't get me wrong, I've been a lot of time trying to get this to work and writing a lot of tests in vain.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use `string` as a variable name; you're overwriting (if `string` is global) or shadowing (if `string` is local) the global string table. I'll be using `varname`.

Simply use `varname` as a key to index `_G`; `_G` is just a regular table after all:

```lua
local varname = "variable"
print(_G[varname]) -- print the value of the global variable named "variable"
_G[varname] = 42 -- change the value
```

similarly, to list all global variables, you can just loop over `_G` using `pairs`:

```lua
for varname in pairs(_G) do print(varname) end
```

If you want to call the value, use `_G[varname]()`:

```lua
function foo() print"foo!" end
function bar() print"bar!" end
local varname = "foo"
_G[varname]() -- foo!
```

Depending on your specifics, you might instead want to look up the variable in `_ENV` / `getfenv(1)` (which need not necessarily be `_G`) or search the local variables and upvalues using `debug.getlocal` and `debug.getupvalue` respectively.

This seems like an X-Y-Problem though: Why do you need to dynamically index the global table? If you're not the consumer of a poorly designed API, you should be able to re-engineer your API to use its own table rather than polluting the global table. For example, I'd rewrite the above example as:

```lua
local t = {}
function t.foo() print"foo!" end
function t.bar() print"bar!" end
local varname = "foo"
t[varname]() -- foo!
```